# Mac/Linux command : Access from anywhere?

Tags: macos, command

How it is possible to access any installed software from anywhere in linux/mac?

I installed mysql in my mac using homebrew which got installed in /usr/local/mysql.

But if I enter 'mysql' in cmd (terminal), my terminal is recognising 'mysql'. How is that possible? 
Also, I have not set any environment variables.

1. What is the reason behind this?
2. Shouldn't I give the path like, "example : /usr/local/mysql/mysql.someSoftwareExtension" to enter into mysql?

Comment: Try doing `printenv`, or `cat ~/.bash_profile`... when you installed it the path got set someplace.

Comment: I don't think that's an environmental variable. when I echo $mysql I get nothing. As you said during installation of mysql, the path is set somewhere. Where it is?

Comment: Try doing `which mysql`; it might be a symbolic link.